# Logging crosscutting concern needs access to data layer

Tags: language-agnostic, circular-dependency, n-tier-architecture

Say I have an architecture similar to the [Layered Architecture Sample](http://layersample.codeplex.com/).  Let's also assume each large box is its own project.  The Frameworks box and each layer would then be its own project.  If we don't use IoC and instead go the traditional layered approach without interfaces, Service would reference Business which would reference Data and all of these would reference Frameworks.

Now the requirement is that logging be done to the database, so presumably Frameworks would need to reference Service to reach Data.  There are two issues with this:

1. You now have a circular dependency (remember, no interfaces).  Most of this can be solved if you use interfaces with IoC (Dependency Injection or Service Locator) and a composition root.  Is this the only way or can you somehow do it without an interface?
2. If you're in Business and need to log something, it has to make the jump to service again.  Is there any way to only make the jump from Presentation but not from Service/Business/Data without a composition root?

I know I'm somewhat answering my own question, but I basically want to understand if this architecture is feasible at all without IoC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some inversion of control, there is not too much you can do.

Assuming your language supports something like Reflection in .NET you could try to dynamically invoke code and invert the control at runtime. You don't need interfaces but you might have to mark/decorate or have a convention for the types that you need in the upper layers.

I'm just thinking now about crazy, non-pragmatic approaches: you could post-process the binary and inject the logging code in every layer.

Comment: Reflection and all that is beyond what I'm looking for, but thanks for confirming.  Even with IoC you can't really do circular dependency injection unless you're dealing with singletons (at least in Autofac), but at least you have the option.

Answer (score 1):

For this example, I would call the logging methods in the Business Layer where logging is needed. It really doesn't make any sense to call up a level. That would an unnecessary abstraction, and it sounds like you've gathered as much.

Is there any abstraction provided in the Services layer for logging that you would require when logging from the business layer? If so, perhaps some sort of facade could be created for the purpose of business layer logging. If you do not require this abstraction, though, I would call the Business logging methods directly.

Comment: The problem with calling business logging methods directly is that it would require a circular reference.

Comment: If you are calling business logging methods from the business layer, dependencies shouldn't be a concern. A layer doesn't need to reference itself. You only have an issue with circular dependency if you are trying to reference the service layer and call the logging methods there from business.

Comment: I may be answering my own question here... The service layer would be something like a web service which inherently has to have an interface (even though I said no interfaces) to make the jump to another app domain, so no circular dependency there.  A circular dependency within one app domain would be Business -> Data -> Crosscutting (for logging) -> Business (for logging to DB), but this should work: Business -> Data -> Crosscutting -> Service -> Business, with the caveat that I'm making a jump across the network (localhost) to reach the service when I'm already in the service.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Since Logging is cross cutting concern, it should not refer your Data layer. In your question, I see that you had assumed that you are logging into the database. Even if this is your requirement, you have to keep database connection/insert of log records code as seperate from your application data Layer. It will be part of your Logging library rather than part of Data layer. Do NOT treat it as part of data layer. It is this perspective with which you can continue to develop/enhance logging [framework] as well as it will be seperate from your data layer.

From My perspective, data layer only constitues of Application Data Access and not logging. For concrete you can see, NLog or Log4Net libraries and see how they are not concerned with Application's data Access layer strategy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may be onto something here.  I assumed I should be able to reuse my auto-generated DAOs.  Let's suppose you're right.  How would my web tier which doesn't have direct access to the DB log?  Wouldn't it go through the business layer?  Or could we technically say it's not "business logic" so there should be a separate project/service which would be the "crosscutting logic layer"?  By separating it out I think the dependencies wouldn't be an issue unless crosscutting code fails and it tries to log, then we're back where we started.

Comment: @Nelson pls ignore above.How would my web tier which doesn't have direct access to the DB log? Logging decision depends upon your application architecture. It does not matter, when you look it from Logging perspective. Think it as reusable component/framework/service built for regular n-tier/3 tier architecture. Inside logging project/service, you won't refer to business logic/data layer of application. Logging is independent of any application layer. If "logging to database" fails then you can log to some text file or better into specified machine's event log.